# How can I resize these divs while keeping the same layout?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Sorry for the title, it's a hard issue to summarise. At the moment, I have a website which looks like this:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/a0vAo.png]

(as you can tell, it is inspired by Metro). I have uploaded it to jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/r46bY/4/embedded/result/

The div surrounding everything (represented by a dotted border) resizes to fit the user's browser window and I want the buttons (which are simply coloured divs) to do the same but can't figure out how. At the moment, they're in place using absolute positioning and based on a particular screen size. I would like them to keep the same layout but resize along with the container div.

I've experimented with liquid values in CSS, but I can't get the positioning right.

Please help.

Comment: Use percentage values instead of fixed-widths.

Comment: It's not *liquid*, it's *fluid*..  I don't think a fluid CSS layout would work well with absolute positioning in any case .. it's also very unclear (at least to me) what you're trying to do.  Perhaps you could also give an example of expected output vs. actual output?

Comment: I just started using a framework that does stuff like this for you.  Here's a link to the framework:  http://foundation.zurb.com/  and another to an article about it: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/dive-into-responsive-prototyping-with-foundation/

Comment: I would suggest looking into the CSS properties: table, table-cell, table-row, and table-column.

Comment: Please include your code in the question so after the jsFiddle link goes dead this is not totally useless.

Comment: Get the user's window dimensions and then adjust all of the divs accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use only percentages instead of pixels for your dimensions (including margins). At resize you only have to resize the surrounding div, and the content should take the right dimensions.

Comment: Thank you, but how do I position the buttons so that they fit that layout?

Comment: You need to think everything in percents. For example, you could make a row of 4 buttons, each of them with width=24%; and margin:1%